# Regarding awk command

Tags: awk

Can any one tell me how can i add a particular word in whole file using `awk` command.

data look like this:

```
Organism: ahy   
matching miRNAs 
    miR156a
    miR156b
    miR156c
    miR159
    miR167
    miR3512
    miR3519
    miR394

Organism: aly   
matching miRNAs 
    miR156a
    miR156b
    miR156c
    miR156d
    miR156e
    miR156f
    miR156g
    miR156h
    miR157a
    miR157b
    miR157c
    miR157d
    miR159a
    miR159b
    miR159c
    miR160a
    miR160b
    miR160c
    miR161
```

Now I want that output to look like this:

```
Organism: ahy   
matching miRNAs 
ahy miR156a
ahy miR156b
ahy miR156c
ahy miR159
ahy miR167
ahy miR3512
ahy miR3519
ahy miR394

Organism: aly   
matching miRNAs 
aly miR156a
aly miR156b
aly miR156c
aly miR156d
aly miR156e
aly miR156f
aly miR156g
aly miR156h
aly miR157a
aly miR157b
aly miR157c
aly miR157d
aly miR159a
aly miR159b
aly miR159c
aly miR160a
aly miR160b
aly miR160c
aly miR161
aly miR162a
aly miR162b
aly miR163
```

Please suggest to me how can I do this using an `awk` command. I am beginner and I am trying but did not find how can I add a particular word in the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `awk` is the right tool for such tasks. Assuming all data is in one file as shown in the question, try:

```
awk '
  /^Organism:/  { prefix = $2 ; print ; next }
  /^matching/ || !NF  { print ; next }
  { print prefix, $1 }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is better with `sed`, like: `sed 's/\ / ahy /g'` and `sed 's/\ / aly /g'`. It will replace any space character for `ahy` or `aly`.

It is also possible with `awk`, but I could not understand how your data is stored :-/

EDIT:

Try this 
`awk '{if ($1=="Organism:") {word = $2; print $0} else { if ($1=="matching") {print $0} else {print word $0}} }' filename`

Answer (score 0):

As asked executed by `awk`

```
awk '/^Organism/{prefix=$2}/miR[0-9]{3}/{$0=prefix $0}1'
```